# Is it good programming practice to supply numeric arguments to logical operators like & in R?

Tags: r, logical-operators

Lately, I have noticed some people use the "&" operator in R in this manner:

```
c(1:5) & c(6:10)
#[1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

or another example

```
c(-2:1) & c(3:6)
#[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

Here (https://mobile.twitter.com/drob/status/1008410647472803840/photo/1) is one of the most recent examples of such use from a world class data scientist (see lines 3 and 4 for an example).

I was initially baffled trying to figure out what R was doing but soon noticed all non-zero numbers are automatically converted to TRUE while zero is automatically converted to FALSE. Later, I also read in the R-help file that:

> Numeric and complex vectors will be coerced to logical values, with
>   zero being false and all non-zero values being true.

My questions are :

1. a.)  What advantage does such programming style provide? It is a bit terrifying to know that if I accidentally provided R two numeric vectors with "&", it will provide results based on automatic conversion without any warning (potentially doing something I was not even planning to do)! 
   b.)   Should not logical operators be required to take in logical values as arguments?
2. Do other programming languages allow such automatic conversion of numeric to logical values? Is this standard practice?

Thank you very much for any insight you can provide

Comment: You read the language definition, so you know this is legal.  A big argument about whether it is good practice isn't really appropriate on this site.

Comment: In defence of David's example, he was drawing from `rbinom(n, 1, 0.5)` which will only give `1` or `0`. Using `1:5` etc for logical comparisons is rather confusing imho.

Comment: @user2554330 thank you for alerting me that the question may not be pertinent to the objectives of this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It just saves you the trouble of converting numeric values to logical, nothing more nothing less.

Yes, other languages do the same thing. For example in python

```
if 1:
    print("yes")
```